# Utilizando MySQL com o R no pacote RMySQL

Tags: mysql, r

Sou novo quando o assunto é o MySQL e instalei esse programa para utilizar com o R.
Consegui instalar a biblioteca RMySQL, seguindo tutoriais que encontrava na internet e no curso que estou fazendo no Coursera como

http://biostat.mc.vanderbilt.edu/wiki/Main/RMySQL e

http://www.ahschulz.de/2013/07/23/installing-rmysql-under-windows/

Até tentei instalar uma biblioteca mais antiga do RMySQL segundo:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43073782/rmysql-system-error-10060

Utilizando o código:

```
require(devtools)

install_version("RMySQL", version = "0.10.9", repos = "http://cran.us.r-
project.org")
```

Porém nada disso funcionou.
Quando fui testar o MySQL, me conectando com o MySQL do UCLA utilizando o seguinte comando:

```
ucscDb <- dbConnect(MySQL(), user="genome", host="genome-mysql.cse.ucsc.edu")
```

Apareceu o seguinte erro:

```
Error in .local(drv, ...) : 
Failed to connect to database: Error: Lost connection to MySQL server at 
'reading authorization packet', system error: 10060
```

Acredito que isso aconteceu por problemas na instalação do MySQL. Será que alguém tem alguma dica ou sugestão?

Answer (score 2):

O método mais fácil de instalação do RMySQL no R para Windows é via `install.packages`.

Faça o seguinte:

**Passo 1:**
Instalação normal do R para Windows https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/

**Passo 2:**
Abra o ambiente R e instale a versão mais recente do RMySQL a direto do CRAN:

```
> install.packages("RMySQL", repos="http://cran.r-project.org")
Warning in install.packages("RMySQL", repos = "http://cran.r-project.org") :
  'lib = "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.4.0/library"' is not writable
also installing the dependency ‘DBI’

tentando a URL 'http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/DBI_0.6-1.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 745244 bytes (727 KB)
downloaded 727 KB

tentando a URL 'http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/RMySQL_0.10.11.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 2296883 bytes (2.2 MB)
downloaded 2.2 MB

package ‘DBI’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘RMySQL’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
        C:\Users\alastori\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpwLAGXJ\downloaded_packages
```

**Passo 3:** 
Teste a conexão com o MySQL

```
> library(DBI)
> ucscDb <- dbConnect(RMySQL::MySQL(), user="genome", host="genome-mysql.cse.ucsc.edu")
> result <- dbGetQuery(ucscDb,"show databases;"); dbDisconnect(ucscDb);
[1] TRUE
> result
              Database
1   information_schema
2              ailMel1
3              allMis1
4              anoCar1
5              anoCar2
...
```

Divirta-se!

Comment: alastori, obrigado pela resposta. Essas etapas eu já tinha feito e o erro persiste:

    Error in .local(drv, ...) : 
      Failed to connect to database: Error: Lost connection to MySQL 
    server at 'reading authorization packet', system error: 10060

Acredito que seja um problema na instalação do MySQL que não estou conseguindo instalar da forma correta.

Comment: @T.Veiga tente conectar ao MySQL utilizando o MySQL Workbench que vem com ele.

Comment: Você não precisa instalar o MySQL Server neste caso. O servidor está do lado de lá e o que você instala com o pacote RMySQL é um Cliente (driver/connector). Você pode fazer um teste de conexão com outro Client, como por exemplo o MySQL Workbench, como o @WilsonFreitas sugeriu. Se funcionar, a conectividade está OK e o problema está realmente no RMySQL. Se não funcionar com outro client, provavelmente algum problema de rede/conectividade. Como você viu no meu exemplo, eu consegui conectar normalmente, então não há problemas com o MySQL Server que está na UCLA.

Comment: Outras pessoas estão com o mesmo problema e isto está como um issue aberto no GitHub do projeto RMySQL https://github.com/rstats-db/RMySQL/issues/193 . No meu caso está funcionando e minha sessionInfo é esta: > sessionInfo()
R version 3.4.0 (2017-04-21)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

Matrix products: default
...
attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.4.0